# Main thread and workers separated

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, threadpool

Iv feel a bit lost find a good way to get some ideas of how to solve my threading problem C# Unity. What I try to achieve is to offload my main thread from long running tasks. This to avoid the main thread to wait for a or several tasks to finish before the main thread can continue as usual.

Right now I have this test code.

```
    public void Start()
    {
        var workers = new List<DataChunk>();

        workers.Add(new DataChunk());
        workers.Add(new DataChunk());
        foreach (var worker in workers)
        {
            Task.Run(() => worker);
        }
    }
```

The DataChunck is just striped down here for this test and could contain all the procedures that are suppose to be included as a complete task. So right now I just have a timer here to simulate something being done and taking its time.

```
    public class DataChunk
    {
        public bool isDone = false;
        public DataChunk()
        {           
           System.Random r = new System.Random();
           int rInt = r.Next(1000, 2000); 
           Thread.Sleep(rInt);
           allDataLoaded = true;
           Debug.Log("Done " + rInt);
           isDone = true;
        }
    }
```

This dose not really do what I want to achieve in the end, as it only executes these the DataChunks executed as tasks in a row, never letting go of the main thread.

What I believe is missing is making this asyc, so they can be started from the main thread, and then preferably without having to waiting for completion from the main thread. As this should be checked from a queue when ever possible.

Should work something like this if I ware to visualize it.
[image]

Anyone who would like to share what is missing to achieve a threaded or task based behavior like this?

Comment: Mind that in Unity, things might be handled quite differently than in other application types based on dotnet, and I only have experience with the latter. So keep this in mind. If you want to spawn off a CPU-bound Task, you'd usually _await_ a Task, that has been started with Task.Run. If you want to start a couple of Tasks at once and wait until all finish, you'd start them, keep the Tasks and await them all via `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` ... but as I said, in Unity, there may be other ways.

Comment: I am just now reading, what I had in memory were "coroutines", but they seem to be obsolete now. You may want to do some research, though. I really don't know if there are some "special quirks" in Unity about async Tasks.

Comment: BTW: Your example `DataChunk`is sleeping in the CTOR. So, the "simulated work" is done in the lines where you create the chunks, not when the tasks execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling to Thread.Sleep in DataChunk constructor: workers.Add(new DataChunk()), and because of this your Thread.Sleep steps are executed not in parallel.

It's better to move Thread.Sleep logic outside of DataChunk constructor to some DataChunk class method and call this method from Task.Run(() => worker.SomeMethodWithThreadSleep());

Comment: Dimitry is right. All your calls to `Sleep` are currently being done before the loop, and therefore outside of `Task.Run()`. The expression `() => worker` is a function which just returns the worker, so it practically does nothing.